# NetFSMountURLSync not able to use custom mount points?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to programmatically mount some WebDAV and SMB shares and I'd like to give the volumes specific names other than the default. For example, if I mount

> https://my.sharepoint.school.edu/personal/grigutis

I'd like it to appear in the Finder as

> /Volumes/My SharePoint Site
>   or
>   ~/Desktop/My SharePoint Site

Instead of

> /Volumes/grigutis
>   or
>   ~/Desktop/grigutis

I can do this with the mount_webdav command:

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/My\ SharePoint\ Site
$ mount_webdav -s -i https://my.sharepoint.school.edu/personal/grigutis /Volumes/My\ SharePoint\ Site
or
$ mkdir ~/Desktop/My\ SharePoint\ Site
$ mount_webdav -s -i https://my.sharepoint.school.edu/personal/grigutis ~/Desktop/My\ SharePoint\ Site
```

But I can't get this working with NetFSMountURLSync (assume that I've already created the directory):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my.sharepoint.school.edu/personal/grigutis"];

NSURL *mountpath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Volumes/My SharePoint Site" isDirectory:YES];
or
NSURL *mountpath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop/My SharePoint Site" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] isDirectory:YES];

CFArrayRef mountpoints = NULL;
int result = 0;
result = NetFSMountURLSync((__bridge CFURLRef)url,
    (__bridge CFURLRef)mountpath,
    CFSTR("Kerberos"),
    CFSTR("NoPassword"),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &mountpoints);
```

If I try mounting to /Volumes/My SharePoint Site, I get the Finder dialog:

> 'There was a problem connecting to the server "my.sharepoint.school.edu". You do not have permission to access this server.'

and the function returns result 13 (Permission denied).

If I try mounting to ~/Desktop/My SharePoint Site, then it mounts like this

> ~/Desktop/My SharePoint Site/grigutis

Which is not what I want. I've filed [a bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/12788358) about this. Any ideas? I'd like to avoid NSTask if possible.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this solved?

Comment: Also, where did you find out what the error codes meant?

Comment: No, Apple just marked my bug report as _Behaves correctly_ and closed it. Read the comments in NetFS.h. It says: `A positive non-zero return value represents an errno value (see /usr/include/sys/errno.h).  For instance, a missing mountpoint error will be returned as ENOENT (2).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating the mountpoint beforehand, and enabling the `kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey` in the mount options works:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef mountOpts = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(mountOpts, kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey, CFSTR("true"));
int ret = NetFSMountURLSync(
    (__bridge CFURLRef) url,
    (__bridge CFURLRef) mountPath,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    mountOpts,
    &mountPoints
);
```

Comment: I have this exact problem this smb and nfs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730678/why-am-i-getting-eperm-when-calling-netfsmounturlsync  I set the MountAtMountDirKey to true (boolean not string) and it fails with EPERM but if I set it to false, it mounts, just in the wrong place. No idea why. I gave up, but I'd like to get this working. What magic did you do

Comment: @stu I know I'm four years late, but I just figured this out myself - *you need to urlencode the mountpoint path segments*, i.e. `/Volumes/mount%20point`

Comment: thanks for the info, what's really comical, is that I have no idea what I was doing, what this is for, or even what company I was working for that I might have needed this. I have zero memory of any of this. But should I ever come across it, thanks for working it out.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to:

"*Also, where did you find out what the error codes meant*?" – <sub>Matt Aug 13 '14 at 21:15</sub>

The error codes can be read from the file: /usr/include/sys/errno.h

I.e if you open your terminal and run the following:

```
$ cat /usr/include/sys/errno.h | less
```

which will output the errno.h file and send it to less so you can navigate the result with pgup and pgdwn keys.